# How to delete lines that do not overlap a polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, line

I'am new to QGIS and I run into a problem. I have two shapefiles, one with line data and one with polygon data. I would like to remove all the lines that do not overlap the polygon.

[image]

So remove all the green lines that do not overlap the blue polygon. What is the best way to do this? I tried the difference tool but I was not able to achieve what I intended.